# Python sqlite3 string variable in execute

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to execute this sqlite3 query in Python. I reduced the code to the minimum, sqlite.connect, etc works.

```
column = 'Pron_1_Pers_Sg'
goal = 'gender' 
constrain = 'Mann'


with con:
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT ? FROM Data where ?=?", (column, goal, constrain))
    con.commit()

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for element in rows:
        values.append(element)
```

This returns an empty list.
If I hardcode the strings, it works and returns values.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Parameter markers can be used only for expressions, i.e., values.
You cannot use them for identifiers like table and column names.

Use this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT "+column+" FROM Data where "+goal+"=?", (constrain,))
```

or this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT %s FROM Data where %s=?" % (column, goal), (constrain,))
```

(And don't commit before you have actually finished accessing the data.)

Comment: will this be vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @DrewV Yes, if you allow `column` or `goal` to be controlled by an attacker.

Comment: Damn I had been doing this for a while but never realized it was the proper way.

Comment: Don't do it like this if the formatting variables contain user input!

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `c.execute("SELECT {idf} FROM Data WHERE {goal}".\
    format(idf=column, goal=constrain))`

Answer (score 1):

I was having quite a similar problem today. I am not sure, if this might solve your problem:

```
cur.execute("SELECT ? FROM Data where ?=?", (column, goal, constrain,))
```

Important is the last **,**

Give it a try, this was the problem with my code - so maybe it helps you too. Sorry, for not being able to really explain why, as I am just learning myself and am into python/sqlite for some weeks.

Comment: A `,` at the end is needed only for tuples with one element, to differentiate them from a plain expression.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. But I can explain something: That is, because the provided value has to be a tuple.

Comment: While this did not directly answer the OP question, it provided valuable insight to me today since I, too, am new to Python and couldn't understand why my single parameter was failing... until Duckduckgo found me this.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to drop this here in case anyone finds it helpful:
You can use Python 3's `f-strings` as below: 

Use this syntax if the variable to be passed on to the SQL query is numeric such as an integer
 `cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name={integer_variable}")`

As for strings you can edit the format string as below:
 `cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='{string_variable}'")`
Please take note of the `''` when passing variables that are strings.
You can also use the `f-strings` with multi-line strings, for example:

```
sql_query = f"""SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name={your_variable} ... SOME MORE SQL"""
```

Then finally pass the `sql_query` to the cursor as follows: `cur.execute(sql_query)`

Answer (score 0):

for the fast sql;

//if variable "a" comes from another file (.py or .csv etc.)

```
try:
con = sqlite3.connect('xyz.db')

sql1=" SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name="+ a +" "
with con:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute(sql1)
        
   con.commit()

   rows = cur.fetchall()

   for element in rows:
       print(element)   

   cur.close() 

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error)
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```