# Issue reading columns in sqlite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to create a function that I can call with a column name and have it return the contents of the column from a table (tablename is in the code).

I am past the point of errors but cannot get it to return the values in the column, instead it returns a list filled with the column name that is as long as the fields in the column.

```
def retrieve_data_game(column):
      with sqlite3.connect("gamereview.db") as db:
         cursor = db.cursor()
         cursor.execute ("select ? from game",[column])
         output= cursor.fetchall()
         db.commit()
         return output
```

calling this with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
         a="gameID"
         gameID = retrieve_data_game(a)
         print(gameID)
```

this print statement will return:

```
 [('gameID',), ('gameID',), ('gameID',), ('gameID',)]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated
kind regards

Comment: What are the strange characters `>` and `*` in the code? Likely you should edit the post and remove them. Indent the code with 4 leading spaces to separate it from the rest of the question.

Comment: thanks, that was my first time posting so I tried a bunch of stuff

Comment: in the line `cursor.execute ("select ? from game",[column])`,  why put `column`  into the brackets?

Comment: @wangke1020 `execute` expects an array and indexes the string if you don't pass in an array/tuple

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13881118/2884547 seems to imply that `?` notation isn't acceptable for identifier locations. That doesn't explain what the given substitution is actually doing, but it might help you move forward...