# how do I search with a variable in sqlite in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a variable inside one SQL query using `"+uid+"` but the variable does not seem to be taken into account:

```
import datetime        
import sqlite3 as lite        
import sys

con = lite.connect('user.db')


uid = raw_input("UID?: ")
time = datetime.datetime.now()

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id = "+uid+";")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print row
        print time
```

Comment: For future reference, it's always a good idea to include a description of how exactly your code is failing. What exactly is it doing that you don't expect? If you're getting an exception, include the full traceback. In this case, Rakesh's answer is a better way to do this anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use string manipulation on SQL. It can result in sql-injections.

Change

```
cur.execute("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id = "+uid+";")
```

to (using `prepared statements`)

```
cur.execute("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id=?;", (uid,))
```

Comment: You can write also that you're using `prepared statements` which is a solution for sql-injections.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 cur.execute("SELECT Name FROM Users where %s=?" % (Id), (uid,))
```

also check out this answer 
[Python sqlite3 string variable in execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880786/python-sqlite3-string-variable-in-execute)