# retrieving data from table based on a value from a python variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a function that will retrieve data from sqlite table based on the parameters user provide. This is the function so far

```
def database_retrieve(db_file, id):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)

        with conn:
            sql_command = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = "+id

            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql_command)
            result = cur.fetchall()

            return result

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

db_file = 'testdb.db'
print(database_retrieve(db_file, 'subject1'))
```

This gives me the following error

```
no such column: subject1
None
```

When I add `subject1`, which is an entry under the `id` column in `my_table`, directly to the sql command  like this

```
sql_command = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'subject1'"
```

it works fine and prints all the data.

I am new to sqlite3. Please help. Thanks in advance

These are the links I used to come this far
[Python sqlite3 string variable in execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880786/python-sqlite3-string-variable-in-execute)

https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-retrieve-data-from-specific-rows-in-mysql-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
sql_command = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = "+id
```

The value of sql_command is

```
"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = subject1"
```

As you can see, `subject1` is not in quotes. sqlite thinks it is a column, that's why you see that error.

Instead, do this

```
sql_command = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?"
cur.execute(sql_command, [id])
```

`?` acts as a placeholder for the variable `id`.

The official sqlite3 documentation mentions few others methods 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

The sql_command string being generated should be something like this (Formatted string):

```
sql_command = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = %s AND name = %s" % (212212, 'shashank')
```

Comment: could you post the schema for my_table