# Can you help me to solve problem from Python Sqlite3 with variable?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

I am creating telegram bot, where I take telegram id and placed in a variable.When I use variable in database with queries I get  "TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)".

Without queries, variable works fine.
Here is some of the code:

```
import db
from aiogram import types
import expenses
from typing import List, NamedTuple, Optional

class Expense(NamedTuple):
id: Optional[int]
amount: int
category_name: str

def test_last():
    cursor = db.get_cursor()
    asd = types.User.get_current().id #user id 
    cursor.execute("select id, amount, name "
        "from expense,category where codename=category_codename and user_id= ?" ,asd,
        "order by created desc limit 10")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    last_expenses = [Expense(id=row[0], amount=row[1], category_name=row[2]) for row in rows]
    return(last_expenses)
```

Comment: It seems your SQL code is cut in half by variable asd

Comment: You should also learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of cross products.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for cursor.execute is

1. string for query
2. tuple/iterable of params

so

```
cmd = ("select id, amount, name from expense,category where " +
       "codename=category_codename and user_id= ? " +
       "order by created desc limit 10")

cursor.execute(cmd, (asd,) )
```

should work.

Here is a cheat-sheet (sqlite uses ?) http://bobby-tables.com/python

and here a related [Python sqlite3 string variable in execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880786/python-sqlite3-string-variable-in-execute) question that also explains the parameters and how to provide fieldnames as well.